# INSERT INTO not inserting using bindparam

Tags: php, pdo, sql-insert

Trying to insert a single row into my table. Having a mare, tried to use tens of examples on the `tinterweb` to no success, I must just not understand how PDO works yet.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO table_name (date, link, desc) 
VALUES (:date,:name,:desc)");
$stmt -> bindParam(':date', $date);
$stmt -> bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt -> bindParam(':desc', $desc);
$stmt -> execute();

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $upload);
```

Comment: Then your code is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: via the `<select>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You shouldn't allow any direct input to your query from user.
2. There shouldn't be user-defined table names as well. Your database structure is wrong. It ought to be a single **predefined** table to store data for **all** users. So, it must be a field content, not table name
3. You need to connect to PDO first, and make it properly. See example in [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)
4. So, you'll be able to see errors.
5. From the error you have to know that `desc` is a reserved word and have to be formatted.

So, the code have to be

```
$stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (date,link,`desc`,type) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$stm->execute(array($date,$name,$desc,$type));

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $upload);
```